# NIghtwatch.js error: "Cannot read propery 'equal' of undefined

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to run a simple `Nightwatch.js` test to login, tell the form to remember the login, and then test the cookie to see if a boolean value exists. Every time I try to run the test, I get an Error:

> "Cannot read propery 'equal' of undefined"

which is tied to the callback function for `client.getCookie()`.

Can anyone help me to understand how to fix this error?

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = {
  'Test "Keep me logged in." ' : function (client) {
    client
      .windowMaximize()
      .url('www.mysite.com')
      .setValue('#login > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type="text"]', 'testuser')
      .setValue('#login > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type="password"]', 'testpass')
      .click('#login > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td > label > input[type="checkbox"]')
      .click('#login > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td > input[type="submit"]')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000);

      client.getCookie('RememberMe', function(result){ 
            this.assert.equal(result.value, 'True');
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function is a lexical scope in javascript, so it sets a new reference to the keyword `this`.

Try something like:

```
  client.getCookie('RememberMe', function(result){ 
      this.assert.equal(result.value, 'True');
  }.bind(this))
```

#### Edit:

Seems like `assert` is a member of `client`, so the call, if supported by the framework should be something like

```
  client.getCookie('RememberMe', function(result){ 
      client.assert.equal(result.value, 'True');
  })
```

Comment: I just tested that, and it's still throwing the same error while running tests: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined".

Comment: After doing some more research, I don't think you're able to assert if a cookie has been set: https://twitter.com/nightwatchjs/status/434603106442432512

Comment: Regardless, `client.assert` should not be undefined. Correcting the answer

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest Nightwatch version, cookie support is now native!

Check the docs [here](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getCookie). My only word of caution would be to ask - are you sure you really want to check for the string value 'True'? Or are you rather checking for a boolean value, which would look like this:

```
  client.getCookie('RememberMe', function(result){ 
        this.assert.equal(result.value, true);
  });
```

Another little bit of advice for debugging is, to make sure you are accessing the right cookie, check for it's `.name` too.

Finally, try chaining the getCookie command by removing the semicolon after `waitForElementVisible` so your code looks like this:

```
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000)
  .getCookie('RememberMe', function(result){ 
        this.assert.equal(result.value, 'True');
  });
```

I am not the best person for advice about JS scopes, but it *looks* as if the context of `this` might be one level too nested. Try replacing it with `client` if you are still having trouble.

Luck!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Nightwatch.js doesn't yet support this feature: https://twitter.com/nightwatchjs/status/434603106442432512

Comment: This tweet is from feb 2014. is this still the case? e.g: http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getCookie

Comment: This is not still the case. Support is now native, check my answer :)