# Assert not available in page object? - Cannot read property 'ok' of undefined.

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, assert, pageobjects, nightwatch.js

I have a small nightwatch test that is reading a price and checks if the value is a positive number.

```
    browser.getText ('.price', function(result) {
       var myPrice = Number(result.value.replace('-.','').trim());
       browser.assert.ok(isPositive(myPrice), 'price is a positive number');
    });
```

This works perfectly fine if i put it directly in the test itself, but when i move it in my page object file as a function (like this):

```
checkPrice: function (){
    this.expect.element('@price').text.to.be.visible.before(1000);
    this.getText ('@price', function(result) {
       var myPrice = Number(result.value.replace('-.','').trim());
       this.assert.ok(isPositive(myPrice), 'price is a positive number');
    });
},
```

it throws this error: **"Cannot read property 'ok' of undefined"**. I have tried to change my check using `assert.equal` instead, but it gives the same error, that the property is not accessible. 
I've read here ([NIghtwatch.js error: "Cannot read propery 'equal' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789810/nightwatch-js-error-cannot-read-propery-equal-of-undefined)) that there might be some issue with the `assert` scope as it's a member of `client`, but if i use `client` instead of  `this` it will not see the assert at all anymore: "**Cannot read property 'assert' of undefined"**.

I have also read that `this` can be a tricky thing to use sometimes, but i have limited javascript programming skills so there might be something that i miss from this point of view.

Could you please give me a suggestion why this doesn't work and how can i try in order to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` changes when you enter the scope of the inner function, so you need to save a reference to it.

```
checkPrice: function (){
    var _this = this;
    this.expect.element('@price').text.to.be.visible.before(1000);
    this.getText ('@price', function(result) {
       var myPrice = Number(result.value.replace('-.','').trim());
       _this.assert.ok(isPositive(myPrice), 'price is a positive number');
    });
},
```

Comment: so it was both about <code>this</code> and scope. awesome, thanks! :-)